# How to assign return of async value to initial state of reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_infinite_scroll_1

I have a reducer. It has a prop called `list`. `createList([], 0)` calls remote api and gets data, then assign to `list`.

./reducers/loadMore.js

```
import { MORE_LIST } from "../actions/types";
import { createList } from "../utils/func"; 

const initState = {
  list: createList([], 0) // <--------------------
};

// able to fire
export default function list(state = initState, action = {}) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case MORE_LIST:
      return {
        list: action.list,
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

./utils/func.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from "axios";

// clone the array
export function createList(arr=[],start=0) {
  let apiUrl = "http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0?p=0";

  return axios.get(apiUrl).then((obj) => {
    let arr = obj.data.manga; // array of obj

    //console.log("--- start ---");
    //console.log(arr);  

    return arr;        
  });
}
```

The issue I have with `function createList(arr=[],start=0)` is
`arr` has data from remote api, but it is not able to return back to `list` in  `./reducers/loadMore.js`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel that making ajax requests in your initial state for your reducer is an anti-pattern.

Instead, I would just have the initial state as an empty array and then either as your app starts or in an appropriate component's lifecycle (`componentWillMount` for example) I would dispatch an action to fetch the data.

You can use indicators like loading bars/spinners etc. to indicate to the user that data is coming back. Additionally, you can perform a check on the length of your array or just do a `.map` on the empty array anyway and this won't get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your createList returns a Promise. So in your `client/actions/loadMore.js` you need to do:

```
return createList(list, list.length+1).then((tmpList) => {
    dispatch({
      type: MORE_LIST,
      list: tmpList
    });
});
```

Also, as [patric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3363019/patrick) mentioned, the following code in `client/reducers/loadMore.js` is async,

```
const initState = {
  list: createList([], 0)
};
```

the `initState.list` here is a Promise. Instead initialize it with empty list and dispatch the loadMore() action in the ComponentDidMount method of your component/container